# Installing OneSignal on React Native - linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, reactjs, react-native, linker-errors, onesignal

I am about to install OneSignal to my React Native application. I have installed OneSignal successfully with [the documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup#section-ios-installation) (at list without "Notification Service Extension").

Then I started to follow the documentation to install the "Notification Service Extension" as well. However, after I installed the "Notification Service Extension" correctly (followed the OneSignal documentation instructions) including the Bridging Header I get an error.

My error is located in the target of `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension`. This is my error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTSRWebSocket", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libReact.a(RCTInspectorPackagerConnection.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTReconnectingWebSocket", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libReact.a(RCTPackagerConnection.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Clearly caused by the `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension`:
[image]

But I don't know why and how to solve this problem.. Google isn't really helping me.. 
My `Header Search Paths` are set correctly like in the documentation:
[image]

The `Link Binary with Libraries` part is also done correct!
[image]

As well the part with `Cocoapods` but I do think my problem has something to do with the `Link Binary with Libraries` part... However, I don't know how to solve this problem..

Would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: Any luck with this, having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error may be coming from your "tests" target.  Most likely you do not have that fully setup in you Podfile.  So, it tries to embed your ServiceExtension as part of your tests and you get this error.

2 Solutions - Don't build tests, remove it from the build part of the schema.  I personally do not use xcode tests in my RN projects, so this was my solution.

Other solution - Include a section in your Podfile for your test target and make sure it includes all the RN stuff that is needed.